# Sorting Columns in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has columns

```
ID, F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, TB1, TB2, TB3, TB4, TB5, TB6
```

I need to sort values in `F1` thru `F6` and put them in `TB1` thru `TB6` in descending order. IE the highest value in F1 thru F6 will go into TB1 and the lowest value in F1 thru F6 will got into TB6.

I am very new to SQL so the more detail the better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this will work on mssql 2008.

But cross applying to the values with a pivot works in mssql 2012.

> ```
> -- Sample data
> create table test
> (
>   ID int identity(1,1) primary key,
>   F1 int,
>   F2 int,
>   F3 int,
>   F4 int,
>   F5 int,
>   F6 int,
>   TB1 int,
>   TB2 int,
>   TB3 int,
>   TB4 int,
>   TB5 int,
>   TB6 int
> );
>
> insert into test 
> (F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6) values
> (10,6,4,8,2,12),
> (9,5,1,3,null,7);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS
> (
> select *
> from test t
> cross apply 
> (
>   select *
>   from
>   (
>     select Fn
>     , row_number() over (order by Fn desc) rn
>     from (values (F1),(F2),(F3),(F4),(F5),(F6)) v(Fn)
>   ) s
>   pivot 
>   (
>     max(Fn) 
>     for rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])
>   ) p
> ) a
> )
> -- select * from CTE
> update CTE
> set TB1 = [1],
>     TB2 = [2],
>     TB3 = [3],
>     TB4 = [4],
>     TB5 = [5],
>     TB6 = [6]
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from test
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 |   F5 | F6 | TB1 | TB2 | TB3 | TB4 | TB5 |  TB6
> -: | -: | -: | -: | -: | ---: | -: | --: | --: | --: | --: | --: | ---:
>  1 | 10 |  6 |  4 |  8 |    2 | 12 |  12 |  10 |   8 |   6 |   4 |    2
>  2 |  9 |  5 |  1 |  3 | null |  7 |   9 |   7 |   5 |   3 |   1 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=20ef211f7779b7590b667df50e4aff5f)*

Comment: Heh, thx for the feedback.  I had no way to test it on a 2008, so couldn't be sure.  But I guess 2008 then already had the apply & pivot.